# I can't find the modifier apply button

Tags: blender-osm

Premise: I am trying to use Blender to make a 3D map and embed it in Spatial.

I am using the following video as a reference to create it, but is it a difference in the Blender version?
（The Apply button for the modifiers (which appears at 5:15) does not appear in my version.

The Blender I am using is 3.6.5.
If anyone knows, please let me know.

video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mj7Z1P2hUWk&t=315

Comment: I’m glad you mentioned the timestamp in the video, but it’s best to have screenshots. Meanwhile, I’ll post an answer about this. Yes, the UI did change.

Comment: Hover the cursor over the modifier panel and hit Ctrl-A or use the little drop-down menu at the R/H end of the row of icons on the modifier.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there was a UI change. The apply option for modifiers is now tucked away in a pull-down.[image: see? (had to draw in my cursor as my screenshooter won't show it)]

For more information,see [The Blender Manual, modifiers introduction.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/introduction.html)

Comment: OMG！
I didn't notice the botton!!!
Thanks!!!